# Array does not stacking Class object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to initialize and then append Class object to array through delegate func. Delegate Double comes from button press with some data.

```
var expensesArray = [SpendedMoneyObject]()
var delegatedDouble:Double = 0.0

func setExpenses(expensesFromMainView: Double) {
    delegatedDouble = expensesFromMainView
  var  aSpendedMoneyObject = SpendedMoneyObject(moneySpent: delegatedDouble)
    expensesArray += [aSpendedMoneyObject]
    self.tableView.reloadData()   
}
```

Problem here is that I am trying to show array at TableViewCell, but it doesn't showing at all, I guess main problem is that expensesArray value is 1 and it's not stacking but replacing same array with other value. Will be really happy to hear what you think.

Edit: 
I tried .append and it still the same also TableView func cellForRowAtIndexPath does not getting called.

```
class ExpensesTableViewController: UITableViewController, ExpensesEnteredDelegate{

//MARK : Properties
var expensesArray = [SpendedMoneyObject]()
var delegatedDouble:Double = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
func setExpenses(expensesFromMainView: Double) {

    delegatedDouble = expensesFromMainView
  var  aSpendedMoneyObject = SpendedMoneyObject(moneySpent: delegatedDouble)
    expensesArray.append(aSpendedMoneyObject) 
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return expensesArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier =  "ExpensesCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExpensesTableViewCell
    print("Iam here")
    let expense = expensesArray[indexPath.row]
    let fromDoubleToString = "\(expense.moneySpent)"

    cell.loadItemsToCell(fromDoubleToString, date: expense.date)



    return cell
 }
```

Object class:

```
class SpendedMoneyObject {
var moneySpent: Double
var currentTime = NSDate().toShortTimeString()
var date: String

init(moneySpent: Double) {
    self.date = currentTime
    self.moneySpent = moneySpent

}}
```

Edit: I can now add more than one array by moving new ViewController creation from spendButton func which was creating newVC every time i clicked button. Here are edited code:

```
protocol ExpensesEnteredDelegate {
func setExpenses(expensesFromMainView: Double)
 }

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var moneyTextField: UITextField!



 var delegate: ExpensesEnteredDelegate? = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Defining ExpensesVC
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newExpensesVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExpensesTableView") as! ExpensesTableViewController
    delegate = newExpensesVC

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func spentButton(sender: AnyObject) {


    // Delegating expenses Double value
    if (delegate != nil) {
       let myDouble = Double(moneyTextField.text!)
        let expenses: Double = myDouble!
        delegate!.setExpenses(expenses)
    }


}}
```

But still array's data does not showing up in a tableView

Comment: Just a kind note: "Thanks in forward" is not a real thing! You may have been thinking about "thanks in advance" instead, which is grammatically correct - but note that it's also considered rude in many cultures to thank "in advance". Just ask your question, you'll thank people once they've answered. :)

Comment: `+=` of array is actually just `.appendContentsOf` method, which should not replace the original one. You may want to check how many times `setExpenses` is actually been called, and where from.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it's not stacking but replacing". Also, since this appears to be an issue with `UITableView`, you should post that code as well. More code == more help.

Comment: @EricD Thanks for lesson :) I updated my question with TableView Cell code, but as i said cellForRowAtIndexPath does not getting called

Comment: @ryantxr when i said "it's not stacking but replacing" i mean after delegate func get called data of array getting replaced not adding another array as i want.

Comment: Perhaps try `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)` instead of `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)`

Comment: @ryantxr i found that i was creating new TableView as delegate every time on button click, so now it's adding arrays on stack but still doesn't showing them on tableView cell's

Comment: You should edit your question and show how you are invoking this view controller.

Comment: Are you setting the datasource and delegate on Storyboard?

Comment: @ryantxr if in storyboard it's setts automatically , yes and i can see it in storyboard TableView Connection Inspector.

Comment: Storyboard does not set delegate and datasource automatically.

Comment: @ryantxr does i didin't done that in cellForRowAtIndexPath tableView func?

Comment: Add protocols `UITableViewDatasource` and `UITableViewDelegate` to your controller. Go into Storyboard, select the tableview, go to the connections pane and drag dataSource and delegate to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code example:

```
 let aSpendedMoneyObject = SpendedMoneyObject(moneySpent: delegatedDouble)
 expensesArray.append(aSpendedMoneyObject)
```

Or you can use `.extend()` method if you are looking to append more elements from a different array to your array.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
expensesArray += [aSpendedMoneyObject]
```

try

```
expensesArray.append(aSpendedMoneyObject)
```